# Creating nested JSON from flat json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

i have a flat array like below. Need to separate based on material.

{
"headerList": [{
"Material": "0950418867",
"Plant": "1C03",
"MaterialType": "1045",
"Procurement": "E",
"Component": "87566340",
"Description": "Mat1",
"Quantity": "10",
"Prod": "true",
"Cost": "X",
"SortString": "1"

```
},
```

{
"Material": "0950418867",
"Plant": "1C03",
"MaterialType": "1045",
"Procurement": "E",
"Component": "875663401",
"Description": "Mat2",
"Quantity": "10",
"Prod": "true",
"Cost": "X",
"SortString": "1"
}, {
"Material": "0950418867",
"Plant": "1C03",
"MaterialType": "1045",
"Procurement": "E",
"Component": "875663402",
"Description": "Mat3",
"Quantity": "10",
"Prod": "true",
"Cost": "X",
"SortString": "1"

```
}, {
    "Material": "1950418868",
    "Plant": "1C03",
    "MaterialType": "1045",
    "Procurement": "E",
    "Component": "875663410",
    "Description": "Mat1",
    "Quantity": "10",
    "Prod": "true",
    "Cost": "X",
    "SortString": "1"
}, {
    "Material": "1950418868",
    "Plant": "1C03",
    "MaterialType": "1045",
    "Procurement": "E",
    "Component": "875663402",
    "Description": "Mat12",
    "Quantity": "10",
    "Prod": "true",
    "Cost": "X",
    "SortString": "1"
}, {
    "Material": "1950418868",
    "Plant": "1C03",
    "MaterialType": "1045",
    "Procurement": "E",
    "Component": "875663403",
    "Description": "Mat13",
    "Quantity": "10",
    "Prod": "true",
    "Cost": "X",
    "SortString": "1"

}]
```

}
I want to create the array to nested json object like below. I'm not familiar in json object, but I was trying like loop through the array items an populating to new array if Material matches. It's not success. Please suggest. Thanks in advance.

```
 {
    "headerList": [{
        "Material": "0950418867",
        "Plant": "1C03",
        "MaterialType": "1045",
        "Procurement": "E",
        "itemsList": [{
            "Component": "87566340",
            "Description": "Mat1",
            "Quantity": "10",
            "Prod": "true",
            "Cost": "X",
            "SortString": "1"
        }, {
            "Component": "875663401",
            "Description": "Mat2",
            "Quantity": "10",
            "Prod": "true",
            "Cost": "X",
            "SortString": "1"
        }, {
            "Component": "875663402",
            "Description": "Mat3",
            "Quantity": "10",
            "Prod": "true",
            "Cost": "X",
            "SortString": "1"
        }]
    }, {
        "Material": "1950418868",
        "Plant": "1C03",
        "MaterialType": "1045",
        "Procurement": "E",
        "itemsList": [{
            "Component": "875663410",
            "Description": "Mat1",
            "Quantity": "10",
            "Prod": "true",
            "Cost": "X",
            "SortString": "1"
        }, {
            "Component": "875663402",
            "Description": "Mat12",
            "Quantity": "10",
            "Prod": "true",
            "Cost": "X",
            "SortString": "1"
        }, {
            "Component": "875663403",
            "Description": "Mat13",
            "Quantity": "10",
            "Prod": "true",
            "Cost": "X",
            "SortString": "1"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object that allows you keep track of which materials you've come across. If you have already, simply push the appropriate values in a new object onto itemsList. If not, create a new object with the base properties, and an itemsList array with only one object, containing the other properties.

Then generate the array form that like (using Object.values() for example). Like so:

```js
const headerList = [{ "Material": "0950418867", "Plant": "1C03", "MaterialType": "1045", "Procurement": "E", "Component": "87566340", "Description": "Mat1", "Quantity": "10", "Prod": "true", "Cost": "X", "SortString": "1"
},
{ "Material": "0950418867", "Plant": "1C03", "MaterialType": "1045", "Procurement": "E", "Component": "875663401", "Description": "Mat2", "Quantity": "10", "Prod": "true", "Cost": "X", "SortString": "1" }, { "Material": "0950418867", "Plant": "1C03", "MaterialType": "1045", "Procurement": "E", "Component": "875663402", "Description": "Mat3", "Quantity": "10", "Prod": "true", "Cost": "X", "SortString": "1"
}, {
    "Material": "1950418868",
    "Plant": "1C03",
    "MaterialType": "1045",
    "Procurement": "E",
    "Component": "875663410",
    "Description": "Mat1",
    "Quantity": "10",
    "Prod": "true",
    "Cost": "X",
    "SortString": "1"
}, {
    "Material": "1950418868",
    "Plant": "1C03",
    "MaterialType": "1045",
    "Procurement": "E",
    "Component": "875663402",
    "Description": "Mat12",
    "Quantity": "10",
    "Prod": "true",
    "Cost": "X",
    "SortString": "1"
}, {
    "Material": "1950418868",
    "Plant": "1C03",
    "MaterialType": "1045",
    "Procurement": "E",
    "Component": "875663403",
    "Description": "Mat13",
    "Quantity": "10",
    "Prod": "true",
    "Cost": "X",
    "SortString": "1"

}]

const materials = {}

for (const item of headerList) {

  const toPush = {
    Component: item.Component,
    Description: item.Description,
    Quantity: item.Quantity,
    Prod: item.Prod,
    Cost: item.Cost,
    SortString: item.SortString
  }

  if (materials[item.Material]) {
    materials[item.Material].itemsList.push(toPush);
  } else {
    materials[item.Material] = {
      Material: item.Material,
      Plant: item.Plant,
      MaterialType: item.MaterialType,
      Procurement: item.Procurement,
      itemsList: [toPush]
    }
  }
}

const newHeaderList = Object.values(materials)

console.log(newHeaderList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example solution:

```js
const rawContent = {
  headerList: [
    { materialId: 1, materialType: 100, itemCost: 50, itemQuantity: 1 },
    { materialId: 2, materialType: 200, itemCost: 20, itemQuantity: 2 },
    { materialId: 1, materialType: 100, itemCost: 30, itemQuantity: 2 },
    { materialId: 3, materialType: 300, itemCost: 40, itemQuantity: 0 },
    { materialId: 2, materialType: 200, itemCost: 50, itemQuantity: 2 },
  ]
}

const objectWithMaterials = rawContent.headerList.reduce((stack, element) => {
  const { materialId, materialType, ...itemProps } = element;
  if (!stack[materialId]) {
    /* Adding to stack */
    stack[materialId] = { 
      materialId,
      type: materialType,
      itemsList: []
    }
  }
  stack[materialId].itemsList.push(itemProps); 

  return stack;
}, {})

console.log('objectWithMaterials',objectWithMaterials);

const materialArray = Object.keys(objectWithMaterials).map( key => objectWithMaterials[key] )

console.info('materialArray',materialArray);
```

I've created an object with `reduce()` to keep track of used `"materialIds"`. Then with `Object.keys()` I'm turning this object into the desired array.